# Add a sorted event for DataGrid or CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm using a `ListCollectionView` in my ViewModel to represent my data. I'm using the `SortDescriptions` of the `ListCollectionView` for a database query. I want to notify the ViewModel to reload the data when the sorting has changed.

Currently I'm using the CollectionChanged event of the `ListCollectionView.SortDescriptions`:

```
(EnitityView.SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged +=
    (sender, args) =>
        {
            Task.Run(() => ReloadSort());
        };
```

But when I sort more than one column this will get called for every column, and it starts loading multiple times.

Is there a possibility to add something like a Sorted event to the `ListCollectionView` or the `DataGrid` (if possible with something like a attached behavior, I'm not a fan of control inheritance for such little things)? The Sorting-Event of the `DataGrid` won't work for my purpose, because the `SortDescriptions` aren't yet updated when this gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean here is you need to sort your collection after adding the sort descriptors. If you are adding the descriptor from code then i think you can call the `ReloadSort()` after adding them all of them together.. You may need to call `Refresh()` for the `ListCollectionView` later.

Comment: the sort descriptions are added from the gui when you click on the column headers of the DataGrid, therefore I can't influence the way they are added to the Collection